# What would be the best way to implement callback in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, delegates

I am interested in learning how others design their software.  I have used different solutions on different projects, but I have felt that I could have done it better.  My implementations involved use of delegates and observers, but today I couldn't resist asking you how you would write it.

Let's assume that we have the following :

```
class Sensor
{
  ...
  public:
    void sensorTriggered();
};

Class Device
{
  ...

  public:
    void notifyChangesFromHardware(unsigned int inNotificationInfo);

  protected:
    Sensor *fireAlarm_;
};

int main()
{
  Device someDevice;
  return 0;
}
```

How would you design it if you wanted to call "Device::notifyChangesFromHardware" 
from the Sensor object (fireAlarm_)?

Thank you

Comment: How about Boost.Signals2: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/signals2.html ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Yes, I think that would work too!

Comment: signals and slots from Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use function pointers or function object:

```
struct Notifier_Base
{
  virtual void notify(void) = 0;
};

class Sensor
{
  std::vector<Notifier_Base *> notifiers;
  void publish(void)
  {
    std::vector<Notifier_Base *>::iterator iter;
    for (iter =  notifiers.begin();
         iter != notifiers.end();
         ++iter)
    {
      (*iter)->notify();
    }
};
```

See design patterns:  Publisher / Consumer, Publisher / subscriber.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions.  It's actually amusing to see how other developers would have solved it, especially from experienced senior developers like you.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Boost Signals also like Piotr S. suggests. Also, a simple pattern I've used would look like this in your case:

```
template<class NotifyDelegate>
class Sensor
{
  ...
  public:
    // assumes you only have one notify delegate
    Sensor( NotifyDelegate &nd ) : nd_(nd)
    {
    }

    void sensorTriggered()
    {
        unsigned int notifyInfo = 99;
        nd_.notifyChangesFromHardware( notifyInfo );
    }



  private:
    NotifyDelegate &nd_;
};



Class Device
{
  ...

  public:
    void notifyChangesFromHardware(unsigned int inNotificationInfo);

};

int main()
{
  Device someDevice;
  Sensor<Device> someSensor(someDevice);
  someSensor.sensorTriggered();

  return 0;
}
```

Take a look at [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) as well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  It's very helpful and educational to see how others would have done it, and it's very encouraging when my solutions (one that I had in the past) matches close to the ones done by other developers.